# OnItemCommand Not Firing in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the user clicks on the linkButton OnItemCommand no does not fire. When the ItemCommand event is never called. The code run and generates the divs and displays the correct data, so i know the person object is being binded correctly, but clicking the link button does not work as MatchList_ItemCommand is never fired.

I've been searching for days, but nothing I've come across has been able to resolve this problem for me. I'm not seeing anything wrong with this code.

```
<asp:Panel ID="matchListPnl" runat="server" Visible="false">

       <h1>Look Up Person: Results</h1>
       <p><asp:Label ID="matchListLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label> Clicking the name loads it for administration.</p>

       <asp:Panel ID="exactMatchPnl" runat="server" Visible="false">       
          <h2><asp:Label ID="exactMatchLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
          <asp:Repeater ID="exactMatchList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="MatchList_ItemCommand"/>                    
       </asp:Panel>    
       <br />      
       <asp:Panel ID="partialMatchPnl" runat="server" Visible="false">        
          <h2><asp:Label ID="partialMatchLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
          <asp:Repeater ID="partialMatchList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="MatchList_ItemCommand"/>                             
       </asp:Panel>

</asp:Panel>
```

```
 protected void MatchList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            PersonLinkButton btn = (PersonLinkButton)e.CommandSource;
            Person person = btn.Person;
            //person.Refresh();                
            Session["AdminPersonToEdit"] = person;
            LogAdminAction("Show account details on " + person.LastName + ", " + person.FirstName + " (" + person.Uid + ")");
            Response.Redirect("DetailView.aspx", true);

        }
```

```
public class LastNameSearchTemplate : ITemplate
        {
            public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                //add the beginning div tag                
                container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"resultsBox\">"));

                //create the link to the person
                PersonLinkButton personLinkBtn = new PersonLinkButton();
                personLinkBtn.DataBinding += new EventHandler(PersonLinkBtn_DataBinding);
                container.Controls.Add(personLinkBtn);

                //add any extra data about the user
                Label personInfoLbl = new Label();
                personInfoLbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(PersonInfoLbl_DataBinding);

                container.Controls.Add(personInfoLbl);

                //add the end div
                container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Bind person data to a PersonLinkButton. This is the link in the repeater that allows the admin to select a person.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void PersonLinkBtn_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                PersonLinkButton btn = (PersonLinkButton)sender;
                btn.Font.Bold = true;

                RepeaterItem container = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
                Person person = (Person)container.DataItem;
                btn.Person = person;
                //set the text for the link first
                if (btn.Person.LastName != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (btn.Person.LastName != btn.Person.FirstName + ",")
                    {
                        btn.Text = btn.Person.LastName;
                        if (btn.Person.FirstName != string.Empty)
                        {
                            btn.Text += ", " + btn.Person.FirstName;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btn.Text += ", " + btn.Person.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
                else if (btn.Person.FirstName != string.Empty)
                {
                    btn.Text = btn.Person.FirstName;
                }
                else if (btn.Person.Uid != string.Empty)
                {
                    btn.Text = btn.Person.Uid;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Binds person data to a label
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void PersonInfoLbl_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)sender;
                RepeaterItem container = (RepeaterItem)lbl.NamingContainer;
                Person person = (Person)container.DataItem;

                //get first name and uid first

                //next show any student data
                bool showData = false;
                string displayName = string.Empty;
                string uid = string.Empty;
                string dob = string.Empty;
                string ssn4 = string.Empty;
                if (person.IsFound)
                {
                    displayName = person.DisplayName;
                    uid = person.Uid;
                    dob = person.Dob;
                    ssn4 = person.Ssn4;
                    showData = true;
                }

                if (showData)
                {                    
                    lbl.Text += "<br/>Name: <em>" + displayName + "</em>";
                    lbl.Text += "<br/>Uid: &nbsp;<em>" + uid + "</em>";
                    lbl.Text += "<br/>DOB: &nbsp;<em>" + dob + "</em>";
                    lbl.Text += "<br/>SSN4: &nbsp;<em>" + ssn4 + "</em>";
                }
            }
        }
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string adminUid = "blah";
            if (IsPostBack && ViewState["uid"] != null)
            {
                SetMatchListForm(Person.FindByAccount(ViewState["uid"].ToString(),adminUid));
            }
            else
            {
                //If reloading the page, reset to the lookup form
                base.ResetSelectedPerson();
                SetLookupForm();
            }                
        }
```